# Scrape information from Scraped URL

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and is currently learning how to scrape information from a list of scraped URL. I have been able to scrape information from a url by going thru the tutorial in scrapy website. However, i am facing problem scraping information from a list of url scraped from a url even after googling for solution online.

The scraper that i have written below is able to scrape from the first url. However, it is unsuccessful in scraping from a list of scraped URL. The problem starts at def parse_following_urls(self, response): whereby i am unable to scrape from the list of scraped URL

Can anyone help to solve this? Thank in advance.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request

class SET(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    open = scrapy.Field()
    hi = scrapy.Field()
    lo = scrapy.Field()
    last = scrapy.Field()
    bid = scrapy.Field()
    ask = scrapy.Field()
    vol = scrapy.Field()
    exp = scrapy.Field()
    exrat = scrapy.Field()
    exdat = scrapy.Field()

class ThaiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "warrant"
    allowed_domains = ["marketdata.set.or.th"]
    start_urls = ["http://marketdata.set.or.th/mkt/stocklistbytype.do?market=SET&language=en&country=US&type=W"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//table[@class]/tbody/tr'):
            item = SET()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('td[1]/a[contains(@href,"ssoPageId")]/text()').extract()
            item['open'] = sel.xpath('td[3]/text()').extract()
            item['hi'] = sel.xpath('td[4]/text()').extract()
            item['lo'] = sel.xpath('td[5]/text()').extract()
            item['last'] = sel.xpath('td[6]/text()').extract()
            item['bid'] = sel.xpath('td[9]/text()').extract()
            item['ask'] = sel.xpath('td[10]/text()').extract()
            item['vol'] = sel.xpath('td[11]/text()').extract()
            yield item
        urll = response.xpath('//table[@class]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a[contains(@href,"ssoPageId")]/@href').extract()
        urls = ["http://marketdata.set.or.th/mkt/"+ i for i in urll]
        for url in urls:
            request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_following_urls, dont_filter=True)
            yield request
        request.meta['item'] = item

    def parse_following_urls(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//table[3]/tbody'):
            item = response.meta['item']
            item['exp'] = sel.xpath('tr[1]/td[2]/text()').extract()
            item['exrat'] = sel.xpath('tr[2]/td[2]/text()').extract()
            item['exdat'] = sel.xpath('tr[3]/td[2]/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

I have re wrote the code after trying suggestions given and looking at the output. Below is the edited code. However, i got another error that states that `Request url must be str or unicode, got %s:' % type(url).__name__)`. How do i convert the URL from list to a string?

I thought URL should be in string as it is in a For loop.  I have added this as comment in the code below. Is there any way to solve this?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request

class SET(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    open = scrapy.Field()
    hi = scrapy.Field()
    lo = scrapy.Field()
    last = scrapy.Field()
    bid = scrapy.Field()
    ask = scrapy.Field()
    vol = scrapy.Field()
    exp = scrapy.Field()
    exrat = scrapy.Field()
    exdat = scrapy.Field()

class ThaiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "warrant"
    allowed_domains = ["marketdata.set.or.th"]
    start_urls = ["http://marketdata.set.or.th/mkt/stocklistbytype.do?market=SET&language=en&country=US&type=W"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//table[@class]/tbody/tr'):
            item = SET()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('td[1]/a[contains(@href,"ssoPageId")]/text()').extract()
            item['open'] = sel.xpath('td[3]/text()').extract()
            item['hi'] = sel.xpath('td[4]/text()').extract()
            item['lo'] = sel.xpath('td[5]/text()').extract()
            item['last'] = sel.xpath('td[6]/text()').extract()
            item['bid'] = sel.xpath('td[9]/text()').extract()
            item['ask'] = sel.xpath('td[10]/text()').extract()
            item['vol'] = sel.xpath('td[11]/text()').extract()
            url = ["http://marketdata.set.or.th/mkt/"]+ sel.xpath('td[1]/a[contains(@href,"ssoPageId")]/@href').extract()
            request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_following_urls, dont_filter=True) #Request url must be str or unicode, got list: How to solve this?
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield item
            yield request

    def parse_following_urls(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//table[3]/tbody'):
            item = response.meta['item']
            item['exp'] = sel.xpath('tr[1]/td[2]/text()').extract()
            item['exrat'] = sel.xpath('tr[2]/td[2]/text()').extract()
            item['exdat'] = sel.xpath('tr[3]/td[2]/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

Comment: One issue I see is that you have `request.meta['item'] = item` line at the end of `parse` method which does nothing. To add item to request meta you need to do it when creating the `request` object. `scrapy.Request(url, self.callback_func, meta={'item':item})`. Now it should no longer break on `item = response.meta['item']` line.

Comment: it did solve the problem but the output only consists of information scraped from the last URL of the scraped URL list. Is there any other way to edit the code so all information in all URL from the scraped URL list is being scraped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you are trying to do here, it's called - chaining requests.

What this means is that you want to keep yielding `Request`s and keep carrying your filled `Item` in the `Request`
s `meta` attribute.

For your case all you need to do is instead of yielding `Item` yield a `Request` with an item in it. Change your parse to:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//table[@class]/tbody/tr'):
        item = SET()
        item['title'] = sel.xpath('td[1]/a[contains(@href,"ssoPageId")]/text()').extract()
        item['open'] = sel.xpath('td[3]/text()').extract()
        item['hi'] = sel.xpath('td[4]/text()').extract()
        item['lo'] = sel.xpath('td[5]/text()').extract()
        item['last'] = sel.xpath('td[6]/text()').extract()
        item['bid'] = sel.xpath('td[9]/text()').extract()
        item['ask'] = sel.xpath('td[10]/text()').extract()
        item['vol'] = sel.xpath('td[11]/text()').extract()
        urll = response.xpath('//table[@class]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a[contains(@href,"ssoPageId")]/@href').extract()
        urls = ["http://marketdata.set.or.th/mkt/" + i for i in urll]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url,
                                 callback=self.parse_following_urls,
                                 meta={'item': item})
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to change the inverse 5th line

```
item = response.meta['item']
```

to

```
item = SET()
```

then it works!
Actually I didn't realize your "meta"way very much,since I never use this to describe item.

Comment: By changing the last 5th line from `item = response.meta['item']` to `item = SET()` make the code half correct. It is able to scrape information from the list of scraped URL but it is unable to output information by parse(self, response):

Comment: The problem that i am having now is to pass the item from the first parse function `parse(self, response)` to the second parse function `parse_following_urls(self, response)` so that different fields from different URLs can be populated in item. I have actually read thru the scrapy tutorial and example and tried out the code but it did not work. Do anyone have any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: For your "output" word ,did you write the pipeline code rightly?Cuz I use my own pipeline with your spider code  which change the last 5th line then juse succeed(The specific 'exp' thing just be in my item.json),Is this kind of  right output?                                                                                                       My last item is that: [</td>"], "exp": ["<td style="width: 40%">3.50</td>"], "exdat": ["<td>01/06/2018 </td>"]}

Comment: You can still get the scraped info but it is not at the right place in the output data. The last line should consist of all 11 fields but your code does not give the first 8 fields